# How to calculate UVs of a flat poligon mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, uv-mapping

My game generates a flat surface (the floor of a building). It's a flat poligon mesh as shown in the picture:

[image]

The poligon is generated procedurally and will be different each time.

I need to map UV coordinates so that a standard square texture of, say,a floor made of bricks, is properly displayed.

What is the best way to assing the correct UV coordinates to each vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an irregular shape, you might want to "paste" a texture across the mesh(imagine pasting a rectangular sticker across your mesh and cutting away those that fall outside your mesh shape).

For that type of mapping, you might want to use `Mesh.bounds`, which gives you the `bounding box` of your `mesh` in **local coordinates**, which is the area you are going to "paste" your texture over.

```
Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
Bounds bounds = mesh.bounds;
```

Get the vertices of your mesh:

```
Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
```

Now do the mapping:

```
Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
{
  uvs[i] = new Vector2(vertices[i].x / bounds.size.x, vertices[i].z / bounds.size.z);
}
mesh.uv = uvs;
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! I was trying to figure out a bounding square around the mesh and then mapping the vertex coordinates to said square, but I screwed up somewhere. Using the given bounds is far easier :)